# How can I avoid the effect of double-click on a disabled event function?

Tags: jquery, double-click

My program has functions for mouse down events, like 
$('#button').mousedown(function(){//do something});

I can disable or enable these functions with statements like
$('.class').prop('disabled',true); or $('.class').prop('disabled',false);

My problem is that, when disabled, the event functions respond to double-click. Specifically, there is no response to a single click, but another click immediately after causes the response. This happens only in IE--not in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, or Safari.

I have come up with a workaround. I can add
if(!$(this).is(':disabled')){//rest of code}
to each mousedown event, but there are a lot of them.
I am not sure why this works. Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: try a flag. once fired, make it true and always check for false in the handler.

Comment: maybe return false on click.

Comment: This is not a problem of the event firing more than once. When enabled, the events will respond to a double-click correctly by firing twice.  When disabled, the event should not fire at all, but responds to a double-click by firing once.

Comment: I find that I can avoid the problem by applying the if statement,

if($('.class').is(':enabled')){},

to auxiliary functions called by the event functions.  Since there are 14 event functions and only two auxiliary functions, my fix is somewhat less clunky.